# VBA is causing Overflow when assigning cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim d As Variant, f As Range, f_dependency As Range, x As Range, wmax_update As Double, new_finish_date As Date, changed_row_update As Integer, dependency_to_find As Integer
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim srchVal As String
    Dim cell_to_find As Range
    Dim row_to_update As Long
    changed_row_update = Target.Row
    'MsgBox (changed_row_update)
    dependency_to_find = Range("A" & changed_row_update).Value
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I:I")) Is Nothing Then
        wmax = 0
        new_finish_date = Range("K" & changed_row_update).Value
        'MsgBox (dependency_to_find)
        'MsgBox (new_finish_date)
        For Each d In Split(Target.Value, ",")
            Set f = Range("A:A").Find(d, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                If Cells(f.Row, "K") > wmax Then wmax = Cells(f.Row, "K")
            End If
        Next
        'MsgBox (wmax)
        Range("J" & changed_row_update).Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wmax, 1)
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Dependency:" & dependency_to_find
        Set f_dependency = Range("I:I").Find(dependency_to_find, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f_dependency Is Nothing Then
            new_finish_date_depends = Range("K" & changed_row_update).Value
            firstAddress = f_dependency.Address
            Do
                Set f_dependency = Range("I:I").FindNext(f_dependency)
                row_to_update = f_dependency.Row
                Debug.Print "The row to update is: " & row_to_update
                Debug.Print "The new finish date is: " & new_finish_date
                'Range("J" & row_to_update).Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(new_finish_date, 1)
            Loop While Not f_dependency Is Nothing And f_dependency.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

For some reason this line is causing me an overflow error:

```
Debug.Print "The new finish date is: " & new_finish_date
```

Comment: Presumably, `row_to_update` is the cause of the overflow.  What's the value of it when you get the error?

Comment: @Martin it's correct when I look at it debug mode. Prints the right one.

Comment: Can you provide the *values* of `row_to_update` and `new_finish_date` when the error occurs?

Comment: I also updated the original post with the variable declartion

Comment: What does the error message say? Since `row_to_update` is a string, strings don't overflow. I suspect that the problem is to the right of the `=` sign.

Comment: `row_to_update` should be a `Long`, not a `String`, but that shouldn't throw an overflow here.

Comment: Why is `new_finish_date` a `Double`? `Workday` wants a `Date`.

Comment: @BigBen I think you're right,  it's dumping on the new_finish_date

Comment: @BigBen I updated my original post with the updates

Comment: That's still an overflow error? I'd expect `new_finish_date = Range("K" & changed_row_update).Value` to error out.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, it doesn't when I click on the Debug it points me to the Debug print log

Comment: Can you update your post with the complete method?

Comment: @TimWilliams Updated

Comment: You should switch all of your `Integer` to `Long`.  In VBA there's nothing to be gained using Integer over Long.

Comment: Safest to disable events too in case you enter an endless loop. And change this line to `Loop While f_dependency.Address <> firstAddress`. (Suspect Tim's comment is the apposite one here.)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Debug.Print "The new finish date is: " & new_finish_date
> ```

This line cannot possibly throw an *overflow* error. A *type mismatch* maybe, but not an *overflow*.

> ```
> changed_row_update As Integer
> ```

Declaring row numbers as signed 16-bit integer types however... will absolutely blow up with an *overflow* error, as soon as you attempt to assign a value greater than 2^15-1, i.e. 32,767.

Change the declarations to use 32-bit signed integer types instead: `As Long`. You hardly ever need to use an `Integer` these days.

Note that this instruction is making the event handler re-entrant:

> ```
> Range("J" & changed_row_update).Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(wmax, 1)
> ```

Any `Worksheet.Change` handler that modifies the sheet it's handling `Change` events for, **must** disable worksheet events - otherwise the handler is implicitly recursive, and that can cause problems much worse than a run-time error: blowing the call stack that way has a tendency to just crash the host without warning.

And because you'll want to restore this global state regardless of whether an error occurs while executing the handler, you need an `On Error` statement in there:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '...do stuff..

CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    'handle errors...
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1) -- and nice "About Me" in your profile. That made me smile.